# Можете объяснить простыми словами, что выполняет "Class"?

Tags: python, классы

Ребята, учусь по методу: "взяться за проект и учиться по ходу".
Что такое "class"?
Пример:

```
        class OwnerPerson:
            name = ""
            home_city = ""
            native_language = ""
            target_language = ""
```

Comment: по моему, этот тот случай, когда нужно открыть книгу и почитать, что такое классы.

Comment: Добавьте к методу "а когда не знаю, смотрю в учебник для начала, на сайте же спрашиваю или что-то  мелкое, что не найти, или конкретно о том, что непонятно после учебника". `class` - основа ООП, можете почитать про ООП.

Comment: и тут даже одним коротким комментарием не отделаться. Тут как минимум вечерок нужно потратить и почитать. А некоторым людям и пару месяцев.

Comment: Самое главное, если вы проясните - для чего собственно их разработали и что они дают программисту.

Comment: Ваш метод хорош для тех, кто уже в программировании, причем "глубоко". Вот те могут себе позволить и "взяться за проект и учиться по ходу". Но у вас, судя по вопросу, уровень знания практически нулевой. А в таком случае метод оказывается неприемлемым.  Увы. Ну если вы не гений, конечно. Так что не занимайтесь садомазохизмом -  открывайте книгу и читайте.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что необходимо читать учебники, а не задавать совершенно базовые вопросы. А ценности для базы знаний от таких вопросов нет.

Answer (score 2):

Описываю концептуально и упрощенно.

Программа обычно хранит и обрабатывает какие-то данные. Например, программа Телефонная Книга позволяет вводить и хранить данные о людях, их адресах и телефонах.

Так вот, класс - это такой механизм в языке программирования, который позволяет задать две вещи:

1. какие данные храним (имя, фамилия, адрес, список телефонов и т.п.)
2. какие операции с этим данными делаем (добавить телефон, изменить адрес и т.п)

Программа обычно состоит из более чем одного класса (иногда из гораздо большего числа классов). В Телефонной Книге это могут быть классы:

1. Адрес - хранит информацию об адресе и действия с адресом
2. Контакт - хранит информацию о человеке и действия с этой информацией
3. ТелефоннаяКнига - хранит список контаков
4. MainWindow - класс отвечающий за отображение главного окна программы и взаимодействие с пользователем
5. и т.д

Классы описывают какие данные могут храниться и какие операции можно с ними выполнять. Когда программа запускается, в программе будет логика, например при нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить" создать экземпляр класса Контакт. В этот момент работы программы будет создан объект (или по другому экземпляр) класса.

Это уже конкретный контейнер в котором хранятся конкретные значения данных и с которым можно выполнять операции описанные в классе.

Например, при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить телефон" - вызвать операцию "добавить телефон" из класса Контакт передав телефон из поля ввода телефона.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое, дружище!